# Choosing os at startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, microsoft-windows

If I install elementary OS on my pc alongside with Windows 10 by creating partitions manually, will I be able to choose what OS I wanna boot at computer startup?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when installing you'll be given the option to install alongside Windows. This will install GRUB, which will let you choose between windows and elementary each time you start.